# Google Chrome open new tab - Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any keyboard shortcut to open a new tab in Google Chrome?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the official shortcuts documentation OP linked has the shortcut they requested

Comment: @bertieb Don't be jealous. If all people think like you, 50% of question are not in any forum.

Comment: there's a guideline to follow, before asking a question you need to search at-least google. and if you'd have done that, you'd have got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> [google chrome support](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

CTRL + T

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

"Body must be atleast 30 characters"